# .Single(c.=>c.Id==id) method returns NULL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem with the code below. The first seach (loadToUpdate1) is working. It returns the value.
CustomerId also has a value (in debug mode it is 4). The customer with such Id exists. It's in there (in debug mode I can see this customer with Id 4 in the list Customers).
But why does customerToUpdate1 return NULL? At first I thought that they (Id and CustomerId) are different data types. But they are both integers. Why does .Single(c => c.Id == customerId) not work?
Any idea? 
UPD. I tried First instead of Single, but the result is the same (NULL).

```
var loadToUpdate1 = _context.LoadConfirmations.Include(c=>c.Customer).Single(c => c.Id == loadFormViewModel.LoadConfirmation.Id);

var customerId = loadToUpdate1.CustomerId;
var customerToUpdate1 = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customerId);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you get data when you try to get all customers like `_context.Customers.ToList();`?

Comment: To debug this you could change the troublesome line to `var customerToUpdate1 = _context.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == customerId);`, does this return any results?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be vastly better if you used a join?

Comment: @SelimYıldız From the OP: "The customer with such Id exists. It's in there (in debug mode I can see this customer with Id 4 in the list Customers)."

Comment: Which EF version, which db provider?

Comment: Riffing off of @TanveerBadar, since you're including `Customer`, just add `.Select(x => x.Customer).Single()` and get the customer in one statement rather than three...

Comment: Guys, please see the post above. I attached the picture. I don't know what is happening. I tried everything (where, first, single). No method is working.

Comment: I'm more keen to know how you made `Single()` return null; it should throw an exception

Comment: Now post a screenshot of what you see when you're pointing to someCustomer, after you step off to the next line

Comment: I attached the picture. Why null?

Comment: I said AFTER you step off the line. The line is still yellow. Press F10 so the line under it goes yellow. Then post a screenshot

Comment: Sorry and thank you Caius Jard. I'm a stupid newbei. Everything works now. I'm new to Visual Studio and don't know how to debug properly.

Answer (score 3):

In your debug images, you haven't actually executed the query yet. You need to step to the next line for the value of `someCustomer` to be set.

If `someCustomer` could be null than you need to use `SingleOrDefault`.

`First` will return the first result of 1:N. Throws an exception if there are 0 results

`FirstOrDefault` will return null, or the first result of 0:N

`Single` will return the first result of 1:1. Throws an exception if there are 0 or more than 1 results

`SingleOrDefault` will return null, or the first result of 0:1

Comment: @kostinalex it's not a stupid question at all. I've been doing this for almost 2 decades and there are still facets of VS, deubgging , and software development I learn every day.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know how to debug properly. I didn't know that the Visual Studio debugger doesn't show the assigned value when the assignment happens on the break point. Thank you, Caius Jard.